# "Invalid choice" when activating the Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

I'm trying to switch my Python version from 3.7 to 3.6 and I do as user guide says.

I've created the new environment for Python 3.6 in the Anaconda Prompt, and when I run it, it says "done". But when I'm trying to activate it with command: `activate myenv` it says:

> Invalid choice.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the platform you are working on? Windows, linux, mac? Maybe you can try to list the available environments. On Windows you can try this: `conda env list` and if your desired env is not listed than the env wasn't created

Comment: It is windows. I tried that, and when i run it, it is saying : 

(base) C:\Users\Davidovic>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Davidovic\Anaconda3

I dont understand what those it mean, how can I open this to see the list? 
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Then it says you have only the base environment. How did you try to create the new environment?

Comment: I was folowing instructions from: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html  and i created it but i cant activate it, everything i try invaild...

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your conda version try to update with `conda update conda` or you should check the installation folder after the env creation to be sure the installation was successful. `conda info` command will tell you the envs installation path.

Answer (score -1):

<sup>This answer was copied from a revision of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53650627/3.

The OP ([Ivana Davidovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10745288/ivana-davidovic)) solved their own problem and this is intended to be a self-answer.</sup>

---

> I solved my problem, although not really sure how. :)
>
> Maybe it was because earlier, I was trying to manage python manually first. And now I started managing it through conda, and then I was managing it again manually.

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to activate the environment "myenv" and Anacoda is replying you "Well, you don't have such an environment"

To create such environment, with python 3.6, do:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.6
```

For anything else, please give a look to [this great cheatsheet](https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)